# Embedding python in Visual C++

Tags: python, c++, visual-c++, python-embedding

I am trying to embed python in a Visual C++ application using visual studio 2017.

I correctly included the header files path and the lib path from my Python 3.7.0 installation.

I can include the Python.h and pylifecycle.h files but get an error when I try to run the program. My code and error is below.

```
// TestPythonEmbedding.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console     application.
//

#include "Python.h"
#include "pylifecycle.h"
#include "stdafx.h"


int main()
{
    PyObject* myPointer;

    Py_Initialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the errors I get when I try to build the solution.

> testpythonembedding.cpp(11): error C2065: 'PyObject': undeclared
> identifier
>
> testpythonembedding.cpp(11): error C2065: 'myPointer': undeclared
> identifier
>
> testpythonembedding.cpp(13): error C3861: 'Py_Initialize': identifier
> not found
>
> 1>Done building project "TestPythonEmbedding.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Strangely enough Visual studio gives information about Pyobject* and highlights it as if it is identified. I included an image of that.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS4Y8.png)

Comment: `stdafx.h` must always be included first. If you're not sure how precompiled headers work it's generally better to turn them off as you're likely getting no benefit. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2976046/920069

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281372/how-to-deal-with-the-pyobject-from-c-in-python